# Flutter: Navigation Architecture with BottomBar Menu

Tags: flutter

I still don't have full grasp of the build and navigation process in Flutter and was wondering on how to design the main navigation architecture of a more complex app with many pages.

In my case, I have a HomePage with a Scaffold, a Bottom Bar for Navigation and 5 items in it.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),
      body: [Page1(), Page2(), Page3(), Page4(), Page5()].elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  FeatherIcons.home,
                  size: 27,
                  color: (_selectedIndex == 0)
                      ? Colors.yellow[600]
                      : Colors.grey[800],
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _selectedIndex = 0;
                    });
                },
              ),
            // four more Icon Buttons ....
           ]
          ),
         ),
   );
```

and on Page2() for example I have two tabs on the page, and I used the pattern:

```
Scaffold(
   ...
   body: (_index = 0) ? TabPage1() : TabPage2(),
)
```

where I have two IconButtons in the `AppBar.title` to change the index.

Are these bad practices for Navigation? Should I use a PageView for the 5 main pages in the HomePage or what is the best way to handle the Navigation?

Comment: I would suggest that you create a page for Page 2 and use Flutter Tabbar https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/tabs By using Flutter Tabbar you do not have to do this checking **(_index = 0) ? TabPage1() : TabPage2(),**and you can have access to both tab page inside your Page 2

Comment: For the sake of clarity and maintainability, it is a good idea to use the navigation features provided in Flutter. I would definitely suggest using `PageView` as well as `TabBar` in the example you provided.